# LINQ to SQL with Extra Nullable Columns

Tags: c#, linq

We have a data bound Data Grid called that shows how much of a product is being used.

As the name suggests, it has an extra column to specify the amount to adjust this quantity by.

The LINQ to SQL that defines the binding source is

```
public BindingList<MeterRead> QryMeterRead
{
    get
    {
        var list = new BindingList<MeterRead>();
        list.AllowNew = false;
        list.AllowRemove = false;
        var records = ExecuteQuery<MeterRead>(
            @"select
                mr.meter_rd_id,
                mr.meter_id,
                mr.read_dt,
                mr.prev_dt,
                mr.reading,
                mr.demand_reading,
                mr.usage,
                mr.orig_usage,
                mr.prev_usage,
                mr.estimated,
                mr.kvar_reading,
                mr.change_out_from_id,
                mr.multi_mtr_est,
                adjust_dt = convert(datetime, null),
                usage_adjust = convert(integer, null),
                measure_id = convert(integer, null),
                mr.location_id,
                'customer_id' = {0},
                'group_id' = {1}
            from ub_meter_read mr (nolock) 
            where mr.meter_id = {2}
            order by meter_rd_id desc", usageparams.read_customer_id, usageparams.read_group_id, usageparams.read_meter_id);
        if (records != null)
        {
            foreach (MeterRead rec in records)
            {
                list.Add(rec);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

where `adjust_dt`, `usage_adjust` and `measure_id` are added fields. They do not exist in the table, but are there to allow data adjustments.

On our form's Data Grid, changes can be made in the data for committing when the Save button is clicked.

Make some changes on the form, like change the numeric `usage_adjust` value, and the underlying LINQ Data Source picks up those changes.

All good.

If someone (like the guys in the testing department) decides to remove these changes by deleting the `usage_adjust` values, it seems that LINQ is trying to bind them - throwing misleading null reference errors for the Data Grid.

I am guessing others have come across this, but I don't know what to call it or how to search for this type of error condition.

Does anyone know of a good way to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Where is the LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, setting the `usage_adjust` default value to `0` has stopped the errors.

```
const string sqlfrmt = 
    @"select
        mr.meter_rd_id,
        mr.meter_id,
        mr.read_dt,
        mr.prev_dt,
        mr.reading,
        mr.demand_reading,
        mr.usage,
        mr.orig_usage,
        mr.prev_usage,
        mr.estimated,
        mr.kvar_reading,
        mr.change_out_from_id,
        mr.multi_mtr_est,
        adjust_dt = convert(datetime, null),
        usage_adjust = convert(integer, 0),
        measure_id = convert(integer, null),
        mr.location_id,
        'customer_id' = {0},
        'group_id' = {1}
    from ub_meter_read mr (nolock) 
    where mr.meter_id = {2}
    order by meter_rd_id desc";
```

Now, instead of the Data Grid being blank, it has a `0` in it, and I have provided code in the update routine to skip fields with `0` adjustments.

```
partial void UpdateMeterRead(MeterRead instance)
{
    try
    {
        if (instance.usage_adjust != 0)
        {
            sp_ub_adjust_usage(instance.location_id, instance.meter_id, instance.group_id, instance.adjust_dt, instance.usage_adjust,
                instance.meter_rd_id, instance.measure_id, instance.customer_id, BaseContext.CurrentSpid);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err);
    }
}
```

If anyone comes up with an explanation that fixes this issue in the next month or two, I will accept their answer.

Path for me to edit the file at a later date:

```
Drive:\ICIS_7V04T52\in\Main\in\o\in.o.ub\am\Readings\ua\DataDB\uaDB.cs
```

Comment: You are using neither LINQ nor parameterized queries. Your code simply generates a SQL string from data, thus exposing you to SQL injection attacks, formatting problems (as you found out) etc. The `NOLOCK` hint also means that you have locking problems that you (wrongly) assume they will be solved by reading dirty data.

Comment: An actual LINQ query would look like `list = myDbContext.MeterReads.Where(x=>x.meter_id = someValue).OrderBy(x=>x.meter_rd_id).Select(...).ToList()` or the equivalent in query form `from x in myDbContext.MeterReads where x.meter_id =someValue ...`

Comment: I didn't write this, @PanagiotisKanavos. I am not a big fan of data binding. This code is part of a LINQ to SQL class in VS. Since the dataset includes columns that do not exist in the data table, it is manually created in the code-behind. Again, I did not write it. The parameters are not pulled from Form Fields. If there is some better way to word what I am doing, please elaborate.

Comment: That's the point - this isnt' LINQ to SQL code, it's plain old ADO.NET code that just happens to call a method on a L2S context to execute instead of using a SqlCommand directly. I already provided the equivalent LINQ query in the comment. L2S will take the query and generate a parameterized SQL statement so that `Where x.meter_id = someValue` becomes `WHERE x.meter_id = @P1`, execute it with a SqlCommand and pass the ID as the value to the `@P1` parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - How do I use your query to insert the additional columns? `adjust_dt`, `usage_adjust` and `measure_id` are added fields that do not exist in the data table.